# .sh file not working as expected from java

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, sh

I created a .sh file to copy file from one server to another (scp command) which works fine while run the file from shell (copied files into destination).

But I tried to run the same file from Java using the command

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec(myShellScript)`

Which execute the command but file is not copied. I got echo from the `sh` file means the sh file is executed, but no files are copied. Any idea?

Comment: Could you show the exact code with the .sh file and it's content ?

Comment: Since this doesn't happen with *all* shell scripts, we'd need a [mre] -- an example of a specific shell script it *actually does* happen with.

Comment: Since your script can `echo` content to stdout, btw, some good places to start would be to run `pwd` (check that it's running in the directory you expect), `set -x` (to log everything it does to stderr), and `echo "$PATH"` (make sure that mandatory environment variables are appropriately set).

Comment: The script is probably trying to tell you what's wrong. Make sure you can see error messages (on stderr) and not just echos. To get an example error message to look for to verify that stderr is visible, you can use `echo "My Error" >&2` or `ls /filenotfound`

Comment: maybe it has to do something with `#!/` string?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Process Builder](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/) ?

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("path/to/hello.sh");
```

Also make sure the script is executable (chmod u+x filename)

EDIT : If the script is copying files to directories which the user running the Java process doesn't have access to, it will not work unless su or sudo is used

Answer (score -1):

As I can see, you have to execute the script with `sh` instead of just running it.

```java
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sh "+myShellScript)
```

Please have a look on [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) as well.

Comment: That's only necessary if the script isn't executable (both `+x` permissions and a valid shebang), and leads to bugs -- when you force the interpreter to be `sh`, that means a shebang like `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/zsh` is ignored, so an otherwise-working script can try to run with a shell it's incompatible with and fail for that reason.

Comment: Moreover, `exec("sh " + myShellScript)` parses your shell script's *filename* as part of the code passed to a shell itself. If that name contains spaces, or worse, something like `$(rm -rf ~)`, all involved will have a very bad day.

Comment: And even further, the OP says that `echo`s in the script are being run, so any answer that's only applicable to problems that would make the script not run at all are clearly off-base.